# c# events System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, делегаты

```
    public delegate void PriceChangingHandler(double price);
    public double Sum { get; set;}
    public event PriceChangingHandler Added;

    public void Add(T b)
    {
        if(b == null)
        {
            throw new MyOutOfRangeException("Object is null");
        }
        T[] temp = new T[bikes.Length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = bikes[i];
        }
        temp[temp.Length - 1] = b;
        Added(Sum += b.Price); //System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
        bikes = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Added != null && b != null) 
{
  Added(Sum += b.Price);
}
```

Comment: Added?.Invoke(Sum + = b?.Price)